# Magento2 : Redirect Using Plugin (With Website Restrictions ON)

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, plugin, website-restriction

**Postlogin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Postlogin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory
    ) {
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject , $result)
    {
        $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customerhomepage/index/landing');
        $this->_response->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
    }
}
```

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
       <plugin name="Mycompany_Plugin_Postlogin" type="Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Plugin\Postlogin"></plugin>
   </type>
</config>
```

I want to redirect to a custom page after login ,  how to do that by plugin ?

**UPDATE**

The Code Works fine it redirects to Custom page , as soon as the website restrictions are on it stop working

Comment: Please provide more information and not just code. What happens with your current code? Did you make sure that your plugin is executed? Does it throw an error?

Comment: @fschmengler I found the issue , the code is working fine . but as soon as i turn on website restriction  the page is redirected to My account page rather than custom page , how should i fix that. without website restriction it is working fine

Comment: I don't know how website restriction works but it might use a similar plugin that is executed before yours.

Answer (score 7):

You can try like below

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as responseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Test{

    public function __construct(
        responseHttp $response,
        UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject , $result)    {
         $url = $this->_url->getUrl('customerhomepage/index/landing');
         $this->response->setRedirect($url);
         return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone else looking for a solution to `before` plugin, you should return `$subject` instead of `$result`

Comment: @Wildcard27 if there is around plugin then what we have to use?

Answer (score 3):

Thats what worked for me :

```
public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result)
{
    $result->setPath('home-page'); // Change this to what you want
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It works. Simple solution :)

Comment: Its not working